# `grep -l .. | xargs vim` generates a warning, why?

Tags: vim, xargs

If I run a command like

```
grep -rl test . | xargs vim
```

I get a warning "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal." But I am still able to edit the files. Why the warning?

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why

Comment: Use: `vim $(grep -rl test .)` instead.

Comment: Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because Vim is invoked from inside the *pipeline*, the `stdin` is connected to the previous pipeline's output, not the terminal. As an interactive command, Vim needs to receive its input from the terminal.

Better avoid the pipe, e.g. via

```
$ vim $(grep -rl test .)
```

or from inside Vim:

```
:args `grep -rl test .`
```

Comment: In this case, xargs' stdin is the pipeline, not vim's stdin.

Comment: vim's stdin is /dev/null if invoked with xargs.

Comment: @lgeorget, that is not true of all `xargs` implementations. Solaris', and Busybox' at least don't (the spawned processes inherit the stdin of xargs, that is the pipe). That's not a POSIX requirement.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ok, it's worth knowing that. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 9):

Vim needs its standard input to be the terminal where you'll enter commands, but it gets either `/dev/null` or the pipe from `grep` depending on your `xargs` implementation.

You can restore standard input through an intermediate shell.

```
grep -rl test . | xargs sh -c 'vim -- "$@" <$0' /dev/tty
```

If the file names don't contain any whitespace character or any of `\[?*`, you can use command substitution instead:

```
vim $(grep -rl test .)
```

One way to cope with special characters (other than newline) is to restrict word splitting to newlines and turn off globbing.

```
(IFS='
'; set -f; exec vim $(grep -rl test .))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use GNU Parallel instead of xargs you do not get the warning and your terminal settings are not changed afterwards:

```
grep -rl test . | parallel -X --tty vi
```

Added bonus: It works even if filenames contain space, ' or ".